# ClassLoader class dependeny (plugin)

Tags: java, inheritance, plugins, classloader, urlclassloader

I want to ask about UrlClassLoaders. I write a main .jar file which works well. Now I want to make it able to load plugins from one of its folders. I wrote it until that it finds the .jar files in the folder, can list their classes inside (their name, path). The problem is when I ask him to find that class (for create an instance of it) they won't find the class which it inherites from my main jar file like this:

```
IN MAIN JAR:
-class Expansion { ... }

In a plugin jar:
-class ExpansionA extends MainJar.Expansion { ... }
```

So when I ask an UrlClassLoader to resolve the "*ExpansionA*" class it will search for the "*Expansion*" class in the plugin jar instead of the MainJar, and there is no "*Expansion*" class in the plugin jar because it inherites from the MainJar as a resource library... and throws NoDefFoundForClassError exception while the *defineClass* method. How can I tell him to check after the classes in the MainJar too? (Its not only about 1 class but I want the plugin to be able to inherite any class from the MainJar). Can u help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ClassLoader`s have a parent to which load requests are delegated first. To ensure that the new class loader you are creating can access the class `Expansion` you should set the parent of the new `ClassLoader` to the `ClassLoader` of your class `Expansion`:

`ClassLoader myLoader=new`[`URLClassLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html#URLClassLoader%28java.net.URL%5b%5d,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29)`(urls, Expansion.class.getClassLoader());`

This does not only ensure that the `Expansion` class will be found by `myLoader`, it will also guaranty that it resolves to the same runtime class (as the parent is asked first). This is important if the plugin jar contains a copy of the class.